# need header columns in the next line

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to change the columns to the next row .
This is my html code with javascript in it. could any one help me to change the code as required format table shown as output below.

```js
// scroll down for ES6 features. 

// using regular methods.

function tableFromJson() {
  // the json data. (you can change the values for output.)
  var myBooks = [{
      'Book ID': '1',
      'Book Name': 'Challenging Times',
      'Category': 'Business',
      'Price': '125.60'
    }
  ]

  // Extract value from table header. 
  // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
  var col = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
    for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }

  // Create a table.
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  // Create table header row using the extracted headers above.
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // table row.

  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {

    var th = document.createElement("th"); // table header.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  // add json data to the table as rows.
  for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
    }
  }

  // Now, add the newly created table with json data, to a container.
  var divShowData = document.getElementById('showData');
  divShowData.innerHTML = "";
  divShowData.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
th,
td,
p,
input,
h3 {
  font: 15px 'Segoe UI';
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Click the button to create a dynamic table using data extracted from a JSON array.
</h3>
<input type='button' onclick='tableFromJson()' value='Create Table from JSON data' />
<p id='showData'></p>
<p id='msg'></p>
```

Example: https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/practice-ground/default.htm?pg=convert_json_to_table_javascript

[I need this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epJ4o.png)

Comment: Can you please explain more what exactly you need? By running your code I can see output that shows a single row of a tble with table headers.

Comment: Hi Alim, 
use in put as var myBooks = [
            {'Book ID': '1', 'Book Name': 'Challenging Times',
                'Category': 'Business', 'Price': '125.60',
                'Book': '6', 'Book N': 'Challenging ',
                'Category 1': 'Business', 'Price1': '125.60'
            }
        ]
I need output as this

Book ID Book Name Category Price
1 Challenging Times Business 125.6
Book Book N Category 1 Price1
6 Challenging Business 125.6

in table format

sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epJ4o.png

Comment: @mohammadAbdulAlim can you provide your email id. so I can share the more details.

Comment: There are no key/value pairs of `Book Level: '...'` or `Total: '...'` in the JSON. Add those 2 to each object `{...}`  in JSON (ie `myBooks`).

Comment: If you are confused as to how to generate more rows, be aware that the JSON requires a separate object `{...}` for each row. Each object must have identical keys. If you don't already know, the keys are the text in the `<th>`.

Comment: @zer00ne, Can you apply your comments on my code and provide the code please

Comment: Your desired output is confusing ... is that 2 rows for every book item (ie every `{...}` has 2 rows of `<th>` and 2 rows of `<td>`)? Post an example image of the `<table>` with more than one book item.